# move files matching a specific pattern

Tags: command-line, regex, mv

How can I move files in a folder with a specific pattern to the destination folder?

I want to move files with names in the range [00-09] in the 4th column when separated by delimiter "-".

```
ls | cut -d "-" -f 4 | grep ^[00-09]
```

Shows these files:

```
UNCID_376947.TCGA-DD-A118-01A-11R-A131-07.110525_UNC12-SN629_0087_BC03HWABXX.7.trimmed.txt
UNCID_377115.TCGA-CC-5263-01A-01R-A131-07.110525_UNC12-SN629_0087_BC03HWABXX.5.trimmed.txt
UNCID_377252.TCGA-DD-A114-11A-12R-A131-07.110525_UNC12-SN629_0087_BC03HWABXX.6.trimmed.txt
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a glob expression:

```
mv your_dir/*?-*?-*?-0[0-9]* new_dir/
```

To test it, you can firstly perform a `ls your_dir/*?-*?-*?-0[0-9]*` to make sure it matches the files you want.

The expression `*?-*?-*?-0[0-9]*` means: characters + `-` three times and then `0` and any character.

#### Test

```
$ ls
another_dir/  aa-03A-b  aa-b-03A-b  aa-b-c-03A-b  a-b-c-03A-b  a-b-c-23A-b
$ mv *?-*?-*?-0[0-9]* another_dir/
$ ls another_dir/
aa-b-c-03A-b  a-b-c-03A-b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 'for loop':

```
for FILE in 'file-list'
do
  echo "$FILE"
  mv "$FILE" /your/destination/
done
```

Explanation:

`'file-list'` should be replaced with a method to get a list of the files you want to use. For example `$(cat files.txt)` if you already have a list in a file, `pattern*` if the files in your directory start with the same pattern or `$(find -iname "*pattern*"`) if you want to use find to get the list.
The output will be stored in the variable `FILE` one element after the other. The the commands between `do` and `done` are executed for each element. You can use `echo "$FILE"` to check if your command matches the right files before adding the `mv` command to the loop.

Comment: I like the idea of using a `for` loop, so that you may have more control over what you are doing. However, `for FILE in $(expression)` may be a bit redundant: first, because parsing `ls` is not recommended; secondly, because you can directly say `for file in expression*` instead of expanding the result. That is, you better say `for file in *` than `for file in $(ls)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to keep it a bit more general, because your answer already provides a good specific solution for the asker. Maybe a `find` command would also be a good idea in OPs case to get a file list

Comment: About your update: instead of `for name in $(cat file)`, it is way more preferred to say `while read -r name; do ... done < file`. Or if you want to feed with a `find` result, `while read -r name; do ... done < <(find ...)`.

Comment: Yeesh, maybe this works if you have a file listing all the filenames, but that's not what the question asked, and this 'solution' led me down a serious rabbit hole of parsing problems with `ls` and `find`. At least in some circumstances, you cannot use `find` as claimed here, it seems to produce `??` as the filename. Not sure exactly what specifics are causing this and I'd rather spend time googling for a solution that works in my case than troubleshooting this one, so, not really sure what the problem is, but this definitely isn't a generalized solution.